# Why does my Minecraft world keep freezing

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

My wife and I are playing Minecraft on the the Xbox 360, and it will randomly freeze. We have called Microsoft twice, and both times they have said that it "must be over heating." We know that this isn't the case because it doesn't happen on Mass Effect or on Final Fantasy, and it will happen when the world loads. Are there any patches or updates that will help with this?

Note: it is the Xbox 360 disk.

Comment: I don't think calling Microsoft would help you... How long do you play together in one session?

Comment: We play anywhere from half an hour to five hours. But it will freeze as it loads for the first time, or two hours in, or as it is getting to the title screen.

Comment: Hmm, this is quite a strange issue without predictability... I might have to do some looking around on this one...

Comment: Also, what version are you playing on? The latest?

Comment: Yes. From what I can tell we are playing the most up-to-date version.

Comment: After doing a bit of looking around, it appears your issue might be from a slightly corrupted world. On the PC edition you can use MCedit to find and get rid of corrupted chunks. Unfortunately there is no such option for the Xbox360 edition. The most I can do is reccomed that you save at least every half hour, and don't play for more that 3 hours straight, then restart your Xbox. Also, if there are any areas in your world that seem like it always crashes there, try to stay away from those.

Comment: We have it set up to auto-save every 15 min. In addition, we find if we stay closer, it is less likely to freeze up. But it is as we feared, the issue is just going to be annoying but not game breaking.

Comment: Have you installed the game onto the hard drive?

Comment: we bought the disk, and are unable to download the game of Xbox Live without having to buy it again. Our saved worlds are located on the harddrive if that is what you meant.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache yet? Does the problem persist in offline mode?  How about going into offline mode and then saving there and then trying to play the game again online?  If you have multiple worlds, have you tried to back up your worlds to either cloud or USB and then keep in your HDD only one or two main worlds you play on?

Comment: Yes we have cleared the cache. It doesn't matter if we are online or off. We only have one world we play on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you playing split screen? Or xbox Live? It freezes on split screen if more mobs spawn in a world then the limit, (this is a rare bug) You should try another world or delete your current world, if it still happens, its something to do with your internet, (sometimes my xbox freezes to on minecraft) does it happen rarely? Or commonly? I suggest making a new world, or cleaning your minecraft disc

Answer (score 0):

It freezes up on us constantly ... just Minecraft on XBOX 360.  We have to shut it down then restart ... we lose everything from the last save point.  Appears to be a Minecraft cache issue for those that build a lot.  It is definitely a Minecraft coding bug.